# Microsoft Graph API Token Generation From Nodejs Code

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I want to access Microsoft Graph API and for that i am trying to generate Token from Nodejs Code. I am getting Token from nodejs but when i decode this token in jwt.io. i do not see scope parameter. Also when I use this token in accessing Microsoft Graph API it gives error

> Authorization_RequestDenied

Code Generation screenshot

[image]

Comment: Post your code..

Comment: var request = require('request');
const endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token";
const requestParams = {
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
    client_id: "clientid",
    client_secret: "secret",
    scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
};

Comment: request.post({ url:endpoint, form: requestParams }, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Body=" + body);
        let parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);         
        if (parsedBody.error_description) {
            console.log("Error=" + parsedBody.error_description);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Access Token=" + parsedBody.access_token);
        }
    }
});

Comment: My Query is why there is difference in token generated from node js code and postman. From Postman: Token generated is having all the required values to be used in Microsoft Graph API but same parameters i  am passing in Node js code and Token generated is not  having all values like scope is missing because of which i am not able to use in Microsoft GraphAPI

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVjB2.png

Comment: I tried adding content type, but still token generated is not having scope parameter in it. It  is same as was with my previous code

Comment: This is the exact same code which i am using at my end and it generates token. Maybe for you permissions are not present in your app id.

Comment: If i change value as  grant_type=authorization_code, then its asking me to add parameter "code". Could you please help me in knowing how to get value of code here?

Comment: Can you please check if my code looks good for code generation?

Comment: var request = require('request');
request({
  url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=e21cb472-c9e6-4314-a73d-e71b168bdd27&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FRLM&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read&state=12345',method: 'GET',auth: {
   'username': 'username','password':'password'},headers: {'accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json'}},

Comment: function(err, response, body) {
  if (response.statusCode!=200) {
   
   console.log("Error");
   
  } else {
   console.log("response"+JSON.stringify(response));
 
  }
 });

Comment: Its terrible why are you exposing all ur password and credentials here?? Please remove that

Comment: Also which doc you are following?? The code which you have pasted is not in the doc which I posted in answer.

Comment: I have removed it , it was by mistake. Also for generating Code i am following Node js Get Request method with the url you have mentioned below after replacing the correct values.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm90t.png . Please see this screenshot. I am trying this from postman. Same response i am getting from nodejs code. Please let me know how can i get "code" value from node js code.

Comment: @Subburaj, could you please look into this issue

Comment: I think the following is the doc you are looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/node-tutorial. Try to implement using the doc

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for a solution where node js script returns token whenever it is called. There should not be any manual intervention(as mentioned in this link for sign in page). I am not sure if this is even possible in node js as same was achieved in .net

Comment: You said you achieved using `.NET` have that as reference and mimic that in node.js. Look into whether they called an API and getting code without manual intervention. So just mimic what you did using .NET.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, use the [edit] link

Comment: Sure @JamesZ will keep in mind. Could you please help in resolving this issue of generating token without manual intervention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow Clearly say that if

`grant_type: "client_credentials"` the response would be as follows, it `won't have scope variable`

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBP..."
}
```

This is what you are getting, so its working perfectly.

You are looking for `scope` variable, so you have to follow as

`grant_type=authorization_code` , the response is

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5HVEZ2ZEstZnl0aEV1Q...",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read",
    "refresh_token": "AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGAMxZGUTdM0t4B4...",
    "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyZDRkMTFhMi1mODE0LTQ2YTctOD...",
}
```

Here you will get the `scope` variable, reference is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

So the the way you are calling is important whether `client Credential` or `authorisation_code`

**EDIT**

You have to call the `authorise` API as follows:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read
&state=12345
```

Modify your request with the `url` and `params` and you will get the response as follows:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient?
code=AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGBCmLdgfSTLEMPGYuNHSUYBrq...
&state=12345
```

Here is the code you are looking for. SO after this you have to make the above call for token.

Comment: From Node js I am not getting expected response for code generation.

Comment: @krati Agarwal What you are getting?? Any error? or partial response??

Comment: @krati Agarwal paste your code in question part, I can't get your full code from comment.

Comment: This was helpful in .net only as here we have inbuilt functions to access Microsoft graph API. I am not able to avoid sign page in nodejs .

Comment: @krati Agarwal how they avoided signing page in .NET??

Comment: testCredentials = UcwaSfbo.AzureAdAuth.GetAzureAdToken(authenticationContext, sfboResourceAppId, clientId, redirectUri, uc); This is how we are getting token in .net.